# Book for Learning XML and Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a very basic knowledge regarding XML.  But now I want to dig more related to this.  I am using Java so I would like to ask for advise on what particular book is useful in my case.

Can you share with me the best possible book that I could purchase.  I tried to look at amazon but I got discouraged in some of the reviews that these book are out of date while other says that this one is worthless.

My knowledge in java is perhaps ahead of the beginner stage.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I liked Effective XML.  It assumes some knowledge of XML but you can get by with just the basics.

JavaRanch lists [many reviews of XML books](http://www.javaranch.com/bunkhouse/bookSearch.jsp?title=&author=&publisher=&isbn=&review-author=&content=&category=XML).  Most of the reviews for XML are over 5 years old though.

Comment: This is what I notice also on some books.  Some are a bit dated so I am a bit not sure of hitting the purchase on amazon.  As far as XML is concerned, I dont have knowledge about it.  So could I just go on and purchase it?  Thanks.

Comment: This is the first time I see you here. Welcome.

Comment: @Adeel Thanks.  I spend more time on coderanch.com

Comment: @Mark as Mike points out, XML hasn't changed enough to matter.

Answer (score 4):

[Pro XML Development with Java Technology](http://books.google.com/books?id=pQ2h64OBSSAC&lpg=PP1&ots=GQA0OmjjoT&dq=pro%20xml%20development%20with%20java%20technology&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) is fairly new (2006, written against Java 6) and is getting decent reviews.

Also expect that any well-reviewed "general purpose" Java book will come with a section on XML, because XML facilities are a built-in part of Java.

XML is a relatively old, stable technology.  Do not be afraid to buy a slightly older book, if it has been reviewed well.  Much of it will still be relevant.  And what is possibly out of date, you will be able to self-educate through Google and the help of stackoverflow!